# how to use between clause in hql

Tags: java, spring, spring-data

can anybody tell what is the problem in the request :

```
 @Query( "SELECT new com.app.gsc.entities.ListeBI(lm.listeDeCriteres.designation,count(*) as totalNumber,lm.ficheDeMission.dateEtHeurDeDepart) from ListeDeControleDetailsMission lm where  lm.boolDepart=false AND Year(lm.ficheDeMission.dateEtHeurDeDepart)=:year AND  Month(lm.ficheDeMission.dateEtHeurDeDepart) >= Month(lm.ficheDeMission.dateEtHeurDeDepart)=:FromMonth AND Month(lm.ficheDeMission.dateEtHeurDeDepart) <= Month(lm.ficheDeMission.dateEtHeurDeDepart)=:ToMonth  GROUP BY lm.listeDeCriteres.designation" )
List<ListeBI> getIncidentDepartByFromToMonth( @Param( "FromMonth" ) int FromMonth, @Param( "ToMonth" ) int ToMonth,
        @Param( "year" ) int year );
```

the ERROR message:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: unexpected AST node: >= near line 1, column 322 [SELECT new com.app.gsc.entities.ListeBI(lm.listeDeCriteres.designation,count(*) as totalNumber,lm.ficheDeMission.dateEtHeurDeDepart) from com.app.gsc.entities.ListeDeControleDetailsMission lm where  lm.boolDepart=false AND Year(lm.ficheDeMission.dateEtHeurDeDepart)=:year AND  Month(lm.ficheDeMission.dateEtHeurDeDepart) >= Month(lm.ficheDeMission.dateEtHeurDeDepart)=:FromMonth AND Month(lm.ficheDeMission.dateEtHeurDeDepart) <= Month(lm.ficheDeMission.dateEtHeurDeDepart)=:ToMonth  GROUP BY lm.listeDeCriteres.designation]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It has to be this part: `Month(lm.ficheDeMission.dateEtHeurDeDepart) >= Month(lm.ficheDeMission.dateEtHeurDeDepart)=:FromMonth`. I would say there is a problem with your 3 comparisons.